# Why does Ubuntu appear in Windows control panel list?

Tags: system-installation, wubi

I downloaded the file for Ubuntu Installer [ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-i386](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?release=lts&bits=32&distro=desktop&status=zeroc) and I faced many difficulties while installing Ubuntu along with Windows.

I did not find any .iso file to burn to DVD or USB, but I found a .wubi file. After clicking it, I was taken to Ubuntu Installer. I was asked for my username and password, but there was no option to install along with Windows or replace Windows.

The user experience is somewhat similar to Try Ubuntu.  After 3-5 hours of installing, it asked for a reboot.  Ubuntu starting up and it works well, but Ubuntu unexpectedly appears in my program list in the control panel.

Is it the Ubuntu OS that I have installed? Do I have to recover Windows from boot setup after shutting down the system?

Answer (score 0):

You have installed Ubuntu using WUBI, and that installs it just like a windows application, and that's why you see it in the installed programs under Control Panel.

Now to find the downloaded ISO file, just open file manager, or search depending on the version of windows that you have, and do a search for `ubuntu*.iso`.  That will find the Ubuntu ISO file that you've downloaded. If you haven't downloaded the file yet, you can download it [Here](http://www.ubuntu.com/start-download?distro=desktop&bits=32&release=lts).

Once you locate the file, you can either burn a DVD using [Imgburn](http://www.imgburn.com/), or create a bootable USB using [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) or [Yumi](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/).

Comment: But these commands will not work in Windows - do you mean to run these commands in the Wubi install?

Comment: @wilf Thanks for the comment.  I just realized that the OP is using Windows.  Thanks again :)